# Extracting CSS Selectors with Python Regex

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to parse HTML and extract each CSS selector. The problem I'm running into is separating/splitting selectors when multiple are present under the same div class.

```
html = '<div class="col-xl-4 col-md-6"> <div class="card hover-translate-y-n3 hover-shadow-lg overflow-hidden"><div class="position-relative overflow-hidden">'

css = re.findall(r'(?:class=")([^"]*)', html)
```

Current Output:
`['col-xl-4 col-md-6', 'card hover-translate-y-n3 hover-shadow-lg overflow-hidden', 'position-relative overflow-hidden']`

Desired Output:
`['col-xl-4', 'col-md-6', 'card', hover-translate-y-n3', 'hover-shadow-lg, 'overflow-hidden', 'position-relative', 'overflow-hidden']`

Comment: First off, regex is generally not the correct tool to use for parsing HTML. Use an HTML parser instead. Second, why not just call `[item.split() for item in current_results]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just alter your `css` with using `split`,

```
html = '<div class="col-xl-4 col-md-6"> <div class="card hover-translate-y-n3 hover-shadow-lg overflow-hidden"><div class="position-relative overflow-hidden">'
css = re.findall(r'(?:class=")([^"]*)', html)
css = [i for item in css for i in item.split()]
```

Output:

```
In [1]: print([i for item in css for i in item.split()])
['col-xl-4', 'col-md-6', 'card', 'hover-translate-y-n3', 'hover-shadow-lg', 'overflow-hidden', 'position-relative', 'overflow-hidden']
```